# Nodemon installed but can't be found

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, npm-install, nodemon

I've tried uninstalling and and reinstalling nodemon several times both locally and globally with:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

(tried it both with and without `sudo`)

and it seems to install no problem, and gives me:

```
/usr/local/bin/bin/nodemon -> /usr/local/bin/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
/usr/local/bin/lib
    └── nodemon@1.11.0
```

but whenever I run

```
nodemon server.js
```

in my app, I get;

```
-bash: nodemon: command not found
```

Like I mentioned, I've tried the same process but installing locally to my app dependancies, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  What's going on here?  I followed the same process on a different machine, and it worked no problem.

Googling around, I came across some posts that mentioned changing/adding the PATH?  But it's not clear to me if that's or the problem or what that means.

Also, other globally installed npm modules run just fine

Comment: What happens when you type `which nodemon` ? This is what happens for me on my mac `(11:30)  ~/src/CUP [work-rpt] $ which nodemon
/usr/local/bin/nodemon`

Comment: Hi @Alan.  When I type `which nodemon` nothing happens at all.

Comment: The directory which nodemon is installed, is not in your PATH environment variable for bash. `which` shows the executables that can be found via PATH.

Comment: @Alan how do you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nodemon` is not being found by bash.

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file and add:

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/bin/`

Start a new shell to see it work, or run `source ~/.bash_profile` to have it apply to the current session.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Can you explain a little more what's happening here?  Why is nodemon installing to a different location than other npm modules?

Comment: Unsure, but seing nodemon installed in `/usr/local/bin/bin` seems like an issue. Perhaps something is amiss with your `~/.npmrc` file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `sudo` switched as **root** and then just run:

```
$  npm install -g nodemon
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I tried installing with and without sudo.  Just updated my question to clarify that.  The other answer here seemed to solve the problem.

Comment: did you switched as root ?

Comment: Not sure what that means.  Could you explain?

Comment: in your terminal type `sudo su` and access your terminal as `root` . then try the following command and let me know what happens after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su -
export PATH=$PATH:/home/USER/npm
npm install -g --force nodemon

# THESE LINES + START FROM A NEW TERMINAL...
# IN MY CASE

npm install -g --force node-inspector

# TOO
```

Comment: Hello TheOikonomist. Your comment contains only code. It would be great if you could explain this in a few words.